# Jquery Date-picker is not working with angular directive ng-model in Firefox

Tags: firefox, angularjs, angular-ui

I am using simple HTML5 date control which is bound with ng-model directive, here is my code;

```
<input type="date" datepicker id="NextServiceDate" name="NextServiceDate" ng-model="product.NextServiceDate" />
```

I have noticed one thing, if I am not binding date control with ng-model then jquery date-picker works fine, but after binding with ng-model it sets date for the first time but when I am trying to update date, then it's not calling the date-picker.

Please let me know how to achieve this functionality in Firefox.

I have also created a directive for it, but it also doesn't get called when my input type is 'Date'. It works fine with input type 'text'.

```
One23SRCApp.directive('datepicker', function () {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, el, attr, ngModel) {
            $(el).datepicker({
                onSelect: function (dateText) {
                    scope.$apply(function () {
                        var expression = attr.ngModel + " = " + "'" + dateText + "'";
                        scope.$apply(expression);
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: You have to create directive to make it work, google it. I found this one http://www.abequar.net/jquery-ui-datepicker-with-angularjs/

Comment: @chandermani, i have tried in that way also  but it not call directive  if input type is date.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do:

```
$(el).datepicker(...);
```

You directly get the DOM element in the directive link function (the parameter 'el' in your code).

I am not sure what are you doing here:

```
var value = "";
```

The fact that it gets called only once and not after further updates, is mostly because angular triggers all the watchers(ie. calls `$digest()`) when the page first loads.

Comment: I have also tried to bind directly to element like el.datepicker() but it still not trigger that event.and how i should call $digest each time?

Comment: You should not call `$digest` for triggerring anything attached to an angular model. Angular will do it, that's why you `watch` a model.